# How to Assign a single value to whole NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an mutable array of say 20 objects. And it has values like `@"TRUE",@"FALSE",@"TRUE"...`

Now I want to **reset** the all values of array to `@"FALSE"`. Means array having all values as `@"FALSE" (20 times).`

I know how to add, insert at index... **But I want to know that How can I set whole array value to @"FALSE" in a sing line ??? `without using loop and replace object at index... ?**

For example : is it possible

```
thArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
theArray = @"FALSE" ;
```

Thanks...

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use a loop for this.

Comment: The second statement in your example sets the pointer to point to a string, that doesn't work.

Comment: @sosborn: b'coz I have 7 arrays, each having minimum 50 objects and I have to reset those array on single click

Comment: @WTP: yes I know.. Its just an example

Comment: @Maulik, ok, but I don't see why that means you shouldn't use a loop. Are you worried about speed? If so, don't. Just take the 5 minutes to get it working with a loop and then see if there are any performance issues. My guess is that you wouldn't see any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use a C array? If so, you can use `{0, 1}` as C-equivalents of `{FALSE, TRUE}`, initializing a C array with:

```
unsigned short int cArray[20] = {0};
```

or:

```
static unsigned short int cArray[20]; /* all values are zeroes, or FALSEs */
```

This might be more efficient, instead of using an array of `static NSString * const` elements like you're doing now. Testing whether two integers are equivalent is usually faster than testing lexicographical equivalence of two strings, where your program will have to compare each string character by character.

To reset the contents of the array, you can use the C function `memset()`:

```
memset(cArray, 0, 20*sizeof(unsigned short int)); /* set all values of cArray to 0 */
```

If you need a dynamically-sized array, use a pointer with `calloc()` and reset it with `memset()` as previously described. Just remember to `free()` the pointer afterwards, so that you don't get a memory leak:

```
unsigned short int *cArray = NULL;
size_t cArrayLength = 20; /* can be passed in as a value from another method, etc. */
cArray = calloc(cArrayLength, sizeof(unsigned short int)); /* values are initialized to 0 */
if (cArray) {
    /* use cArray... */
    *(cArray + 8) = 1; /* e.g., set ninth element with the value of 1 */
    /* we don't need cArray any longer, so we free it */
    free(cArray);
}
else
    /* error */
```

If you must use Objective-C with `NSString *` or `NSNumber *` instances in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, there is no ready-made method for initialization and you'll need to use a loop or copy a pre-existing array, as described in Justin's answer. He is also correct that a method for creating and populating the array is a good idea, if you want to go in this direction.

Comment: And otherwise, an NSNumber holding a Boolean value can be used.

Comment: can you explain this statement  *(cArray + 8) = 1; ?

Comment: You are dereferencing the ninth memory location that `cArray` points to, in order to set the value of that memory location. Practically, this is identical to `cArray[8] = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

If those were mutable strings inside the array you could do this in just one line:

```
[theArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setString:) withObject:@"FALSE"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
NSArray * initialized = ...array with fifty @"FALSE" values...;
NSMutableArray * a = [initialized mutableCopy];
... mutate a ...
[a setArray:initialized];
```

If you are actually dealing with bool values, C scalars will be faster (see Alex's answer).

Another alternative would be a `CFMutableBitVector`.

Finally, this would also be a good case for creating a function.

Answer (score 0):

1) [Either this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectsInRange%3awithObjectsFromArray)

2) [Or this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectsInRange%3awithObjectsFromArray%3a)

Otherwise without a loop there is no way.

Answer (score -1):

only way i know is

```
  for(int i = 0;i<[theArray count];i++)
    {[theArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"FALSE"];}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but read question carefully I've mentioned that I don't want to use loop !!!

Comment: I know but that is the only way you can do it. at least that's the only way i know how

Comment: This doesn't work anyway. This is Objective-C, not C++. Use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` instead.